# Add and Remove tabs for ArrayPagerAdapter

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter, commonsware-cwac, commonsware

I am trying to add and remove tabs the same way the demo does in my code. I have a toggle button that calls `arrayAdapter.remove` from the `remove()` method exactly how it is done the demo. When `arrayAdapter.remove` is called the tab at the requested position is removed correctly but the changes are not reflected by the header for that tab. Also when I try to click on the last tab after removing one tab nothing happens but the tab I want to remove is removed. If this is the logic to rearrange the tabs how would I get rid of this null tab? I know the fragment for the tab is removed because when I try to swipe to it I can't get to it anymore. I am having similar problems with `add()` to add tabs to the `adapter.setTabsToShow()` is called when the toggle  button is clicked and `add()` and `remove()` are the same as in the demo. I have posted my code below.

```
private void add(boolean before) {  

    int current=mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    SimplePageDescriptor desc=
            new SimplePageDescriptor(buildTag(arrayAdapter.getCount()),
                    buildTitle(arrayAdapter.getCount()),0);

    if (before) {
        arrayAdapter.insert(desc, current);
    }
    else {
        if (current < arrayAdapter.getCount() - 1) {
            arrayAdapter.insert(desc, current + 1);
        }
        else {
            arrayAdapter.add(desc);
        }
    }
}


private void remove() {
    if (arrayAdapter.getCount() > 1) {
        arrayAdapter.remove(1);

    }
}



public void setTabsToSHow() {


remove();

    }
```

Comment: "When arrayAdapter.remove is called the tab at the requested position is removed correctly but the changes are not reflected by the header for that tab" -- I do not know what "the header for that tab" is. "Also when I try to click on the last tab after removing one tab nothing happens but the tab I want to remove is removed" -- I have no idea what you mean by this. "If this is the logic to rearrange the tabs how would I get rid of this null tab?" -- I do not know what a "null tab" is.

Comment: I have 4 tabs. When I call remove() from one tab to remove another tab  the tab I want to be removed is removed successfully. So I can't swipe to it anymore or click anywhere in the list titles for the tabs (which there are still  4 of not 3 like it should be after removing 1) to get to it. So there are still 4 tabs the 3 that I didn't delete and one at the end that does absolutely nothing when I click on it. Not sure what the description for that is but when I try to swipe to it or click on the title to get to the tab nothing happens.

Comment: "which there are still 4 of not 3 like it should be after removing" -- then whatever you are using for your tabs is not reacting to changes in the `ViewPager` contents.

Comment: When you say "whatever you are using for your tabs" what do you mean by that? I was thinking that's what I was using the arrayPagerAdapter for. I guess the main thing i'm trying to figure out is where to look to even started on figuring out why this is happening. Would I need to add code to the remove method in ArrayAdapter?

Comment: "what do you mean by that?" -- well, `ViewPager` doesn't have tabs. Something else works with the `ViewPager` to provide tabs. `TabLayout`, `PagerTabStrip`, a seemingly infinite number of third-party libraries, etc. "I guess the main thing i'm trying to figure out is where to look to even started on figuring out why this is happening" -- I would ignore the tabs for the moment and focus on programmatically determining whether the state of the `ArrayPagerAdapter` and `ViewPager` are what you expect after you make changes. Once you're sure they're OK, then figure out why the tabs aren't in sync.